# How to get data of email templates including variables from table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, email

Actually i am working on email templates that comes from database dyanmically... So  firstly lets share my code :-

```
#Email Content table
id      content                                  created_at  updated_at
1       New Customer Signs up {{$customerid}}    2018-11-18  2018-11-18
```

Sending Email Function

```
    $customerid = 1;
    $email = "kunal100@yopmail.com";
    $data = array('customerid'=>$customerid);
    Mail::send('emails.email-template', $data, function($message) use ($email)
    {   
        $message->from($email);
        $message->to('kunal@yopmail.com', 'myName')->subject('Test');
    });
```

Email template blade file:-

```
<?php use App\EmailTemplate;
 $getcontent = EmailTemplate::getemailtemplate();?>
 {!! $getcontent['content'] !!}
 <?php die; ?>
```

Email Template Model

```
class EmailTemplate extends Model
 {
//
public static function getemailtemplate(){
    $getcontent = DB::table('email_templates')->first();
    $getcontent = json_decode(json_encode($getcontent),true);
    return $getcontent;
}
}
```

Output :

[image]

Expected output :-

```
New Customer Signs up 1
```

I am getting data from table and when i get data i want to print the variable data like i am passing one customerid.. Can anyone hlep me how can i resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.